# Transferring files between PC and Android Sony Z1 Compact (KitKat) without needing app (i.e. via standard USB mass storage)

Tags: usb-connection-mode, usb-mass-storage, sony-xperia

When I plug my Sony Z1 Compact Android phone into my Mac or PC, the phone prompts me to install a program on the PC/Mac.

Can I not just have the phone behave as a standard, common USB Mass Storage class (i.e. like a USB pen drive, hard drive, or SD card), without having to install a program on the host PC?

This is an inconvenience as if wanting to transfer to a PC that's not my own, I may not be in the position to install such a program.

**Update**
This was so easy on Android 2.3 on a HTC Desire Z - plug it into a Mac, PC or Linux desktop (i.e. the host), phone asks which mode it should be in, select the USB storage / harddrive option and then the phone appears as an ordinary external disk on the host machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program that your phone ask to install is [PC COMPANION](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/tools/pc-companion/). You can skip the PC Companion installation.

If you need to connect in MSC mode

In Settings-> Xperia Connectivity->USB connectivity->USB Connection Mode-> MSC

Comment: Still unlucky so far: If I select cancel when it asks to install the PC COMPANION nothing happens on the PC - no drive appears. But the phone says it's charging. (but thanks for offering advice)

Comment: Check your device manager. Right click on your device and select update driver. Windows should automatically install Xperia mtp driver

Comment: I am always able to connect my Xperia Z1 without pc companion

Comment: Regarding "Xperia mtp driver" - I couldn't understand why a specific driver is needed - if the phone presents itself as a common-all-garden generic basic USB mass storage device then the host machine should recognise that without any need for any other drivers.

Comment: In Settings-> Xperia Connectivity->USB connectivity->USB Connection Mode-> MSC

Comment: @therobyouknow is the setting available for you?

Comment: Thanks - this works - MSC mode means that the phone now appears as a drive on my machine - no need to install anything on my Mac, for example. +1 and Accepted answer. Thanks! Upvoted your last 2 comments as well.